# Noether & Schmeidler- Hurwitz-Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the following page from Noether and Schmeidler's 1921 work:

http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0008&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008&LOGID=LOG_0008&PHYSID=PHYS_0013

And pay special attention to note 10 on page 7.
It is not clear to me whether the principal ideals (Hauptideale) were the focus of Hurwitz's work as opposed to Noether and Schmeidler's, or, as I guess,the other way round. Whichever the case, could you illustrate the differences and explain the role of the quaternions in the whole discussion?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any way you could add more English context? I can read much German, but maybe I have some clues.

Comment: I could only find the German original just quoted. Maybe someone else can add the English reference (provided there is a later English version).

Comment: I just meant that if you might make more comments on the subject matter instead of relying so heavily on the German text.

Comment: I am trying to understand the German textbefore drawing any consequences.....

Comment: Nobody is asking you to "draw any consequences," mainly I am asking you to give readers a little help on what specific topic you are reading about. Most people will be *totally unable to read the contents of your link*, so don't you think you could help out?

Comment: I am interested in the topic of ideals (one-sided ideals,their definition, their relation to one-sided modules and so on, both in rings and in number theory.

Comment: No ideas on this??:(